# What is a Spectral Graph Convolution?

Tags: graph-theory, convolution

I'm reading about Graph Neural Networks and I would like to understand more about first-order and second-order approximations of spectral graph convolution.

What is a Spectral Graph Convolution?

What does a first-order (second-order) approximation of a spectral graph convolution mean? Please, some examples are appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how a circulant matrix $C$ can be diagonalized as $C=Wdiag(\hat{C_1}) W^*$ where $W$ is the matrix of the discrete Fourier transform and $\hat{C_1}$ is the DFT of the first row of $C$. Then the [idea](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.09375.pdf) of graph convolution is to generalize by replacing $W$ by the matrix $U$ obtained in diagonalizing the Laplacian $L = UDU^\top$ of some initial graph $G$ with $n$ nodes,  the vectors of $\Bbb{C}^n$ to be convolved being regarded as activations of the nodes of $G$, which is interpreted as telling how the entries of those vectors should be connected

Comment: Maybe you should links us to the paper that you were reading.